# localised ring $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$ is an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, localization

Given the localised ring $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}=\{\frac{a}{b}:a,b \in \mathbb{Z}, 2 \nmid b \}$, I want to show that this is an integral domain.

We choose some fraction $ \frac{a}{b}\in \mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$,where   $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $b \in \mathbb{Z}$, such that $2 \nmid b$ and pick up another fraction  $ \frac{a'}{b'}\neq 0\in \mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$ with $a' \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $b' \in \mathbb{Z}$  such that $2 \nmid b'$. We look at the term $ \frac{a}{b}*\frac{a'}{b'}=0$. Can we just conclude that $a$ and $b$ have to be zero because the only zero divisors in $\mathbb{Z}$ are the zeroes? How could I argue alternatively with the prime ideal $(2)$ ?

Comment: What is your definition of $\mathbf Z_{(2)}$?

Comment: It is $S^{-1} A$ with $A = \mathbf{Z}$ and $S = A \backslash \mathfrak{p}$ where $\mathfrak{p} = (2)$.

Comment: $b$ cannot be zero.

Comment: I think that every localisation of an integral domain is an integral domain (every localisation can be embedded into the fraction field).

Comment: @Joppy That's dangerously close to being circular. At the very least, to do what you propose, you need to prove that the fraction field is actually a field, which includes proving basically the exact result asked about here.

Comment: @Thesinus Where does $\frac{a}{b}$ live in ?

Comment: @Arthur I'm well aware that it's still begging the question, but I think it illustrates that the only possible thing you would need in the proof is the integral domain property.

Comment: @ujsgeyrr1f0d0d0r0h1h0j0j_juj I've edited it. Does it matter to your proof?

Comment: Yes and no. If you say $\frac{a}{b}$ lives in $\mathbf{Q}$, there's a trivial proof (that you can pompously rephrase into saying that $\mathbf{Z}_{(2)}$ is embedded in $\mathbf{Q}$), see the second part of my answer. But if you just write $\frac{a}{b}$ then I think of $\mathbf{Z}_{(2)}$ as an "abstract" localization (representable as quotient of $A\times S$ by some equivalence relation) and then the first part of my answer applies.

Answer (score 4):

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unit and $S$ multiplicative subset of $A$ (contains $1$ by definition), and $S^{-1}A$ the localization. Then $\frac{a}{s} \frac{a'}{s'} = 0$ means that there is an $s'' \in S$ such that $s''(aa' \times 1 - 0 \times ss') = 0$ in $A$. (As $\frac{0}{1}$ is the localization's zero.) With $A = \mathbf{Z}$ and $S = A \backslash \mathfrak{p}$ where $\mathfrak{p} = (2)$ which is the setup you are dealing with, one sees that $a$ or $a'$ must be zero.

*Remark*. If $\mathbf{Z}_{(2)}=\{\frac{a}{b} \in\mathbf{Q}\;|\;a,b \in \mathbf{Z}, 2 \nmid b \}$ then $0 = \frac{a}{b} \frac{c}{d} = \frac{ac}{bd}$ implieds that $a$ or $c$ is zero, same conclusion.

Comment: In other words, to be able to really argue about this, you (often) _need_ to use the definitions. The definition of multiplication of elements in the localised ring, the definition of the zero element $\frac 01$ in the localised ring, and the definition of equality in the localised ring. Put those together, and you get this answer.

Comment: I would rather say that at the very end, you can only calculate. :) You see that if you want to embed $\mathbf{Z}_{(2)}$ in $\mathbf{Q}$.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the slickest proof of this is that $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$ embeds into $\mathbb{Q}$. Then since $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field, all subrings must be domains.

Comment: And why is $\Bbb Q$ a field (and in particular an integral domain)? Doesn't this just puch the burden of proof one more step forwards?

Comment: @Arthur I find it much easier to show that $mathbb{Q}$ is a field

Comment: @Arthur well, maybe not much easier, but easier, it is a matter of writing down an element

Comment: But the _definition_ of $\Bbb Q$ is $\Bbb Z_{(0)}$. Showing that that's a field can't be easier than showing that $\Bbb Z_{(2)}$ is an integral domain, can it?